# php интеграция веб приложения с мобильным приложением

Tags: php, android, ios, laravel, symfony

как создать мобильное приложения из веб приложения на php(laravel,symfony).
каким образом лучше сделать интеграцию? что почитать? и тд 
примерно понимаю что надо написать какоето API.
Приложение - обычный новостной портал без регистраций и прочего.

интеграция веб приложения с мобильным приложением
или как загуглить?

Comment: Наверно с АПИ на PHP и начни https://habrahabr.ru/post/46032/
Потом подумай чем ты это апи будешь дергать, надо ли тебе это вообще или проше запилить адаптив, что выбрать нативное мобильное приложение или писать по старинке? вот это прогугли

Comment: @RaZik [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)